# C++ IF evaluation operand with vector

Tags: c++, if-statement, operands

I know that the evaluation of operands is from left to right and for the ***"&&"*** operand if the left one is false, the right should not be evaluated! but for this line of code with a ***vector*** it does not work like this,

suppose left =1 and v.size = 1; so we do not have v[1]. because there is only v[0] in the vector

```
if ((left <= (v.size() -1 )) && ( v[node].Value > v[left].Value))
    {
        TempMin = left;
    }
```

So i expect that the right operand not be evaluated, but it gives me the 'out of range error'.
any ideas??

***EDITED***

v.size () is 1 and v.size() -1 =0.

I changed to code and find the problem and I think there is a problem with VISUAL STUDIO runtime debugger. because when I just run the code everything works great, but when I debug the code line by line the IF statement does not work properly

```
    if (left <= v.size() -1 ) // first if
    if (v[node].Value > v[left].Value) // right
    TempMin = left;
```

in this situation the first if PASS and there is an error but if I change it to

```
        if (left < v.size() ) // first if

or
        int t = v.size() - 1;
        if (left < t )
```

everything is ok. So it seems there is problem with (v.size() -1 )!!

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I don't believe the subscript operator should throw an "out of range error." Only the `.at()` function will. Are you sure this is the part of the code where your problem is?

Comment: @scohe001 Going off the end with `[]` has undefined behavior. Throwing an exception is a valid manifestation of undefined behavior.

Comment: Wow, so many parentheses! <g> Seriously, that `if` statement can be written `if (left <= v.size() - 1 && v[node].Value > v[left].Value)`.

Comment: Re: "evaluation of operates is from left to right" -- that's true for the logical operators (`&&` and `||`) and for the ternary operator (`?:`) but it's not true in general. The logical operators do it as part of short-circuit evaluation: if the value of the left-hand argument determines the result of the operator, the right-hand argument is not evaluated. So in `false && whatever`, `whatever` will not be evaluated, because the result of the operation is `false`. Similarly, in `true || whatever`, `whatever` will not be evaluated, because the result of the operation is `true.

Comment: @PeteBecker you right. left is already false and I expect that the "whatever" not to be evaluated.

Comment: trust me, there is no problem with Visual Studio. You are doing and/or analyzing something wrong. Either left is not 1 or v.size() is not 1. Or you trigger UB somewhere else and it's manifesting here.

Answer (score 1):

Possible problems:

1. `v.size() = 0`

Then `v.size() - 1` is `size_t` and equals `18446744073709551615` (`2^64 - 1`). So `left <= 18446744073709551615` and you get out of range.

Solution:
`left + 1 <= v.size()` or `left < v.size()` instead of `left <= v.size() - 1`

2. `v[node]` gives you out of range.

Solution:
Add check for `node`

Comment: the idiomatic way is `left < v.size()`

Comment: I would still not mention `left + 1 <= v.size()` , but that is just me

Comment: v.size () is 1 and v.size() -1 =0. I know v[left] is the problem but I say it should not be evaluated because the left operand is already FALSE